# Program that prints out the product of two complex numbers - segmentation fault

Tags: c

I want to write a program that generates vectors `as_re, as_im, bs_re, bs_im, cs_re,` and `cs_im` of doubles, each of length 30,000, generates entries for `bs_re, bs_im, cs_re,` and `cs_im` (any kind of entries will do), and then multiplies the entries of `bs` and `cs` using a function called `multiply`, saving results to as. print one random entry of as to the terminal.

**Note:** that the signature of multiply MUST be what I've written, that is no return type and accepts all six parameters of type double*.

I've watched a lot of videos on pointers but I find it hard to grasp that concept. I think that my `multiply` function changes `a_re` and `a_im` that has different addresses in memory and not the ones I've declared globally. But if I've declared them globally then they should be seen by both the `main` function and the `multiply`?

Here is what I've done:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// declaring the multiply function

void multiply(double* c_re, double* c_im, double* a_re, double* a_im, double* b_re, double* b_im);

// generating the vectors

int n = 30000;

double* as_re[n];
double* as_im[n];
double* bs_re[n];
double* bs_im[n];
double* cs_re[n];
double* cs_im[n];

double* a_re = 0;
double* a_im = 0;

int main(){

   srand(time(NULL)) 

   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){

      //filling the arrays with random numbers of type double* between 1 and 100.

      bs_re[i] = (double*) rand() % 100 + 1;
      bs_im[i] = (double*) rand() % 100 + 1;
      cs_re[i] = (double*) rand() % 100 + 1;
      cs_re[i] = (double*) rand() % 100 + 1;

      multiply(cs_re[i], cs_im[i], &as_re[i], &as_im[i], bs_re[i], bs_im[i]);

      as_re[i] = a_re;
      as_im[i] = a_im;

      printf("The product is %d + %di\n", as_re[i], as_im[i]);
   }

}

void multiply(double* c_re, double* c_im, double* a_re, double* a_im, double* b_re, double* b_im){

   *a_re = *c_re * *b_re - *c_im * *b_im;
   *a_im = *c_re * *b_im + *c_im * *b_re;

}
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal example that reproduces your problem.

Comment: @Elliott - I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: Seg fault means you've accessed memory you dont own. Its possible that you have done something wrong with your pointers OR arrays.

Comment: @APJo - Yes I know but 2 days have passed and I've tried finding where I'm wrong but I can't see it.

Comment: What Elliot means is a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your code snippets are not valid C code. You have assignments outside of functions and probably typos that lead to identical variable names. A compilable example will rule out such errors.

Comment: Aren't assignments outside of functions called global variables?

Comment: Ah, Ok you want to define `n` there. I missed that there is no definition otherwise. Implicit `int` type is part of an ancient standard and should not be used. You should use `int n = 30000;`

Comment: Your function takes pointers of type `double*` but you pass pointers of tyoe `double **` for `a_re` and `a_im`. Doesn't your compiler shout at you?

Comment: Please don't change your code on the fly after answers and comments have been give. No one wants to hunt a moving target. Instead add a fixed version.  Therefore it is important to show us the code you actually compile. Not something losely resembling it. Fixing on the fly will only create new random errors.

Comment: This is exactly what I did compile, I did use int n = 10 it was merely a typo. And yes, my compiler did protest but the errors are quite useless to you if you just started programming with C. To tell you frankly, C must be the hardest language out there. Memory allocation, pointers etc... I don't even see why one should use pointers. There are a lot of tutorials on pointer arithmetic, but none explain why they are needed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221766/discussion-between-gerhardh-and-parseval).

Comment: Your global pointers `a_re` and `a_im` are holding `NULL`and do not point to a valid location. Assigning a value via these pointers will cause undefined behaviour

Comment: 'it was merely a typo' merely?  Copy/paste only code that you tested, else you will waste time/effort on typos:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you probably meant to generate a bunch of random double values and then pass them to the multiply function, but that's not what you have.  Notice all your array declarations like this

```
double* bs_re[n];
```

are **pointer** to double, not double itself.  So when you later do this assignment

```
bs_re[i] = (double*) rand() % 100 + 1;
```

you are making the pointer point to a randomly-generated address, which is more or less guaranteed to eventually point to memory it shouldn't and cause a segmentation fault.

What you ought to do is declare the arrays as double like this

```
double bs_re[n];
```

Then assign them a random value like this

```
bs_re[i] = (double) (rand() % 100 + 1);
```

And then pass the address of (i.e. pointer to) these values into multiply so they dereference to the values you assigned in the above step.

```
multiply(&cs_re[i], &cs_im[i], &as_re[i], &as_im[i], &bs_re[i], &bs_im[i]);
```

And since the multiply function places the answer into *as_re* and *as_im* directly, there is no need for the assignment statements after the call to multiply.

You have some other errors as well, but this should help you get the pointer portion straightened out.

Comment: Thanks! This did indeed cleared up the confusion on how to use the pointers in this example. However I think I do need the assignment after the multiply call since I must generate the matrices as_re and as_im. However what gets printed now is only the addresses of the real and imaginary parts differing by 8 bytes. I tried de-referencing but it still gives me the addresses and not the value.

Comment: The reason it's printing addresses is because of the assignment statements that I said are unnecessary.  You pass pointers to as_re and as_im into multiply, which assigns their values directly.  Then right after the function call you do this assignment as_re[i] = a_re; which sets the value of as_re[i] to the array, which is just a pointer to the first element in the array.  This is why you're seeing memory addresses in the print statement.  Remove these assignments and it should print the actual values you want.

Answer (score 1):

`rand` produces an `int`. You are then instructing the compiler to treat that random int as a pointer to a double, and then deferencing that random small address, hence the crash. Cast the int to a double.